# How/Should to chnage the farm version on my staging and development environment to be the same

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, server-farm

I run `(get-spfarm).buildversion` on my development and on my staging environments and it seems that the build & Revision are different as follow :-

- On the Staging :-

  Major 15 / Minor 0 /build 4481 / Revision 1005
- While on development the numbers are :-

  Major 15 / Minor 0 /Build 4420 /Revision 1017

So how I can make the build and revision to be the same on both environments (dev & staging), and should i standarize the build an revision numbers to be the same on both environments? i have checked these farm info since i am facing problems when restoring site collections from my development to my staging environment, and i was told that these problems might be caused if the build numbers are different ?

Second question, if i should make the build and revision numbers the same, then should i chnage them to my match my current Dev or my staging environment numbers?
Thnaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dev, qa/staging and production farms should always be the exact same version of SharePoint, unless you are testing a Cumulative Update or Service Pack prior to deployment to production.  Having them be the same version lets you simply copy content databases directly down to QA\Staging from production for testing purposes.

To get your dev environment to the same level, you first need to know where you are with both farms.  Fortunately [this page](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2013/03/26/3561010.aspx) shows that your staging environment is on "March 2013 PU" while your dev environment is on "2013 RTM".  The fix is simply to apply the CU/PU to dev and they will be on the same version.

According to [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2013/03/22/3560441.aspx), the March 2013 PU is a mandatory update anyway so you might as well get it on there.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it really put me in the right track to fix the restore problem i am facing. so you mean i should install the "KB 2767999 - SharePoint Server 2013" inside my development machine , is that right?

Comment: That looks to be the one.  As is always the case though, be sure to back up your server *and* databases prior to applying this.  a VM Snapshot usually works fine, unless your dev databases are on a different machine, in which case you have to back those up separately.